# Can Diagon Alley be accessed through the sky?

Tags: harry-potter

We see that Diagon Alley can be accessed through the Leaky Cauldron, by apparition and the Floo Network. In the movie, Death Eaters fly through the Leaky Cauldron and into Diagon Alley. Would it not have been simpler, if possible, to access Diagon Alley through the street's open sky?

Comment: can you? probably, are u legally allowed to fly through london on brooms in day light? probably not.

Comment: As written, you've answered your own question. Can it? Yes, it can.

Comment: you can certainly leave that way

Comment: I did not mean flying as in on a broom, but through half-apparition.

Answer (score 9):

### Probably

I'm not sure we have ever seen anyone *enter* Diagon Alley by air, but we have seen someone *leave* by air:

> And then at last, by the combined force of their spells and the
> dragon’s brute strength, they had blasted their way out of the passage
> into the marble hallway. Goblins and wizards shrieked and ran for
> cover, and finally the dragon had room to stretch its wings: Turning
> its horned head toward the cool outside air it could smell beyond the
> entrance, it took off, and with Harry, Ron, and Hermione still
> clinging to its back, it forced its way through the metal doors,
> leaving them buckled and hanging from their hinges, as it staggered
> into Diagon Alley and launched itself into the sky.
>
> —*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows*

If Harry, Ron, and Hermione could fly out on a dragon, that would seem to indicate that there is nothing preventing one flying in or out of Diagon Alley.

Why wouldn't someone do so?

- Flying around London risks exposure, particularly during the day.
- It might be  a bit rude to land in the middle of people doing their shopping.