# What would happen if a muggle went inside the Diagon Alley? Assuming they could

Tags: harry-potter

I don´t know if the canon specifies whether a muggle can or can´t enter Diagon Alley [In this question](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/135466/can-diagon-alley-be-accessed-through-the-sky), someone asked if Diagon Alley can be accessed through the sky, and apparently it´s possible.

What would happen then if a muggle entered Diagon Alley?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Very little

There's no evidence of anything preventing Muggles from fully experiencing Diagon Alley, once they've gotten inside<sup>1</sup>.

We know that muggles are allowed in Diagon Alley, because we see Hermione there with her parents (emphasis mine):

> "So you don't think I’m a match for Lucius Malfoy?" said Mr. Weasley indignantly, but he was distracted almost at once by **the sight of Hermione's parents, who were standing nervously at the counter that ran all along the great marble hall** [of Gringotts], waiting for Hermione to introduce them.
>
> <sup>*Chamber of Secrets* Chapter 4: "At Flourish and Blotts"</sup>

In fact, it's been [suggested on this site before](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/q/75909/31051) that muggles can, in certain situations, simply enter through the Leaky Cauldron.

Of course, I expect most muggles would have a bit of a hard time processing what they were seeing and, as ThruGog mentions in comments, uninvited muggles would almost certainly eventually be rounded up, obliviated, and sent on their merry way. But in the meantime, there's no reason to believe that muggles are prevented either from entering or seeing everything Diagon Alley has to offer.

---

<sup>1</sup> Of course, I would heartily expect it to be difficult for a muggle with no magical ties (for example, being the parent of a witch or wizard) to get there in the first place. It would be a bit of a blow to the International Statute of Wizard Secrecy if the city of London, for example, accidentally built a Tube station underneath it.

Comment: Thanks for answering! Didn´t know that, so in theory they could just buy a wand in Olivander´s? That doesn´t make a lot of sense

Comment: @user70014 In theory, sure. But I imagine they'd have a hard time finding a wand to "choose" them

Comment: haha that´s funny, but it´s still strange, i mean i don´t imagine a muggle seeing a goblin and not freakin out

Comment: The crowd has spoken.

Comment: @user70014 - JKR has said somewhere that a Muggle could never successfully use a wand, or that the wand even gives off unpleasant effects, so I don't think Ollivander would sell them one. And if he did, it wouldn't have chosen them and apparently wouldn’t work. I also assume that if a Muggle was found to have sneaked in uninvited, wizards would alert the Ministry who would Obliviate them

Comment: @ThruGog [Probably this interview you're thinking of](http://www.accio-quote.org/articles/2006/0801-radiocityreading1partial.html)

Comment: @Jason Baker - I think so - cheers!

Comment: @user70014 ...who said they wouldn't freak out? :P

Answer (score 5):

Doing a little guesswork here but...

We know that spells are used to either hide (Fidelius Charm) or make other locations just seem unvisitable (what is done at Hogwarts).  In book 1 it's mentioned that muggles just pass by the Leaky Cauldron, which is the entrance to Diagon Alley.  Though I can't find anything specifically saying so, the paragraph from Harry first arriving there implies that something magical is behind that.

From Sorcerer's Stone (or Philosopher's Stone)...

> "This is it," said Hagrid, coming to a halt, "the Leaky Cauldron. It's a
>   famous place."
>   It was a tiny, grubby-looking pub. If Hagrid hadn't pointed it out,
>   Harry wouldn't have noticed it was there. The people hurrying by didn't
>   glance at it. Their eyes slid from the big book shop on one side to the
>   record shop on the other as if they couldn't see the Leaky Cauldron at
>   all. In fact, Harry had the most peculiar feeling that only he and
>   Hagrid could see it. Before he could mention this, Hagrid had steered
>   him inside.

From Goblet of Fire...

> '[Hogwarts is] bewitched,’ said Hermione. ‘If a Muggle looks at it, all they see is a mouldering old ruin with a sign over the entrance saying DANGER, DO NOT ENTER, UNSAFE.'

Moving on to the actual question of what would happen if they got in... There are 2 possibilities:

1. Nobody notices that they SHOULDN'T be there, tossing them up to being a squib or a muggle parent or spouse of a witch/wizard
2. If they figure out the muggle shouldn't be there, they'll simply be obliviated and dropped off somewhere in accordance with the International Statute of Wizarding Secrecy

Answer (score -5):

If a person has any ounce of logic once they see past all the flashy glamour they would immediately figure out the bank and go there to see if they can set up an account and have their money from home exchanged to the wizard currency.

If they play it cool they could blend in for quite a while actually being opened to other cultures and experiences without being too obvious about it especially if they pick up some of the lingo.

If questioned they could say they are an exchange student or some made up story that isn't too off the wall.

Hint: Most muggles aren't as stupid as you think it's just they never get talked about and the (paid) media focuses on the stereotypical ones too much since they get all the ratings.